# Android recycler view not updating when I click button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-button, buttonclick

I have this fragment where I have and edit text , a button and a recycler view. When I click the button for the first time it has the expected behavior but if I change the edit text content and click the button again it doesn´t update my recycler view. What am I doing wrong? Since I am repeating the process
of making an Api call every click

### Fragment

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RestaurantAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected static List<Restaurant_> restaurantsList;
    private Context context;
    private static OnRestaurantClickedListener listener;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private EditText keyword;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;


    public SearchFragment() {
    }

    public static OnRestaurantClickedListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getContext();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        restaurantsList = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new RestaurantAdapter(context, restaurantsList, getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContentView.getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        keyword = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
        keyword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if ((keyEvent != null && keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH))
                    getRestaurants();
                return false;
            }
        });

        ImageButton searchButton = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return mContentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (OnRestaurantClickedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnButtonClicked");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getRestaurants() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                    String sort = mSettings.getString("sort", "rating");
                    String order = mSettings.getString("order", "desc");
                    double radius = Double.parseDouble(mSettings.getString("radius", "10"));
                    radius = radius * 1000;
                    RetrofitZomato.getApi().searchByName(keyword.getText().toString(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),
                            20, radius, sort, order, getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.user_key))
                            .enqueue(new Callback<SearchResponse>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<SearchResponse> call, Response<SearchResponse> response) {
                                    if (restaurantsList.size() != 0) {
                                        restaurantsList.clear();
                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    List<Restaurant> restaurants = response.body().getRestaurants();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.size(); i++) {
                                        double distance = calculateDistance(Double.parseDouble(restaurants.get(i).getRestaurant().getLocation().getLatitude()),
                                                Double.parseDouble(restaurants.get(i).getRestaurant().getLocation().getLongitude()),
                                                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                        distance = (double) Math.round(distance * 100d) / 100d;
                                        restaurants.get(i).getRestaurant().setDistance(distance);
                                        restaurantsList.add(restaurants.get(i).getRestaurant());
                                        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(i);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<SearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    builder.setMessage("Couldn't find any nearby restaurants");
                                    AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
                                    mDialog.show();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(getActivity(), new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It wasn't possible to determine your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private double calculateDistance(double latRestaurant, double lonRestaurant, double myLat, double myLon) {
        if ((myLat == latRestaurant) && (myLon == lonRestaurant)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            double theta = myLon - lonRestaurant;
            double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(myLat)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(latRestaurant))
                    + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(myLat)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latRestaurant)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
            dist = Math.acos(dist);
            dist = Math.toDegrees(dist);
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
            return dist;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.search) {
            getRestaurants();
        }
    }
//    @Override
//    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
//        searchViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SearchViewModel.class);
//        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
//    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't declared your OnClickListener. In the onCreate()  declare your button and set button.setOnClickListner(your_context). Should work

Comment: it is declared on the end of `onCreate` and `onClick` is on the bottom of file

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry. I did not notice it was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that with every `getRestaurants` call you are calling `getFusedLocationProviderClient` and `addOnSuccessListener`, keeping old one registered and left... maybe these multiple instances of listeners are reason of this behavior?

move this line to `onAttach`

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
```

for getting called once. then make your `SearchFragment` implementing `OnSuccessListener` and set for `FusedLocationProviderClient`. your click should fire request for new location, and your current code with `getLastLocation` may be also handled in `onAttach`

edit: real answer - comment copy

try to remove `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(i);` line and move `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` out of `if` condition on the end of method (after for loop). I don't see nothing suspicious in your code, looks fine...

Comment: i didn´t understand the last part

Comment: put some `Log` in `onSuccess` and in `onResponse` - check what it is printing with first and all further (not working) clicks

Comment: "and your current code with getLastLocation may be also handled in onAttach " this part

Comment: `getLastLocation` will return last location, as suspected. but you aren't calling nowhere `requestLocationUpdates`, so this last location is fixed and never changes if any other app in background isn't requesting for location also. I'm assuming that last location should be used on start `Fragment` (so in `onAttach`), but for real current location (not from 2h ago..) you should request new location with every button/`ENTER` click

Comment: check with logging when are `onSuccess` and `onResponse` methods gets called, how often. print attributes which are passed into them (`Location`, which will be same object with every call, and `Response<SearchResponse>` is this proper response, respecting passed query from `keyword` `TextView`

Comment: I do request a new location every click. My problem is that for example I search "Wok" , the list updates to Wok to Walk restaurants. If I search for McDonald's next and click the button it stays the Wok to Walk list. But if e click on an item and see the details and then press back to return to the list, the McDonald's list is in there

Comment: try to remove `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(i);` line and move `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` out of `if` condition on the end of method (after `for` loop). I don't see nothing suspicious in your code, looks fine...

Comment: Done. If you don´t mind can you take a look at this question please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779965/android-how-to-set-location-in-map

Comment: @snachmsm need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495233/retrofit-call-inside-an-adapter-in-android