# Android-How to set location in map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

I have this map and I want to set the location to the lat , lon that I receive in the Intent extras.How can I do it?

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private String lat;
    private String lon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        lat=getIntent().getStringExtra("lat");
        lon=getIntent().getStringExtra("lon");
        mMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in `onMapReady`

```
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng= location.getLongitude();
// set up marker and add
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat , lng))
            .title("Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
// move camera to it
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 8));
```

always do all map-related features like drawing polygons, adding markers, moving camera etc. after `onMapReady` call, so when `googleMap` won't be `null`. And remember that even if it gets called every time for you - in some circulumstances it may not get fired on some device and every `googleMap.someMethod()` call (e.g. under `onClick`) will throw you `NullPointerException`. be prepared for that